# div class randomly positioned in center

Tags: html, css, position

[Live site.](http://parlourdc.com/wp/services)

Toward the bottom of the page `"Parlour Policies"` is floating in the middle of the page, though it should be styled according to this:

```
.content {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Any ideas what's causing the location shift? I didn't see anything in Firebug, and the few validation errors(which I'm working to fix right now) all pertain the WP generated header and don't negatively effect any of the other `<div class="content">` on different pages.

Comment: maybe becuase you have 2 div's with class "content"!

Comment: i'm new to this, so forgive if i'm mistaken, but i was under the impression that `class` allowed multiple/repeated elements? also, i have multiple `class` elements on all pages, why is this not effecting them?

Comment: @Jawad you can have *any* number of elements with the same `class`. That's the `id` that should be unique.

Comment: @ZoltanToth: Yeah got that. In looking at firebug in firefox, I saw two div's with class content and two style declartions and naturally thought the last one in order won over the first one. But you answer seems to nail the problem in the head. Thanks.

Comment: @Jawad you can even have multiple elements with the same `id` - and they all will be styled correctly. However it won't validate and will confuse your Javascript in case you try to select an element by `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden` to `.content` - it will clear your floats

```
.content { 
    height: 100%; 
    padding-bottom: 40px; 
    padding-left: 20px; 
    overflow: hidden; /* this */
    width: 600px; 
}
```